# echo a colored text with tabs

Tags: shell-script, echo

I have the line below to echo values with tab between them. The text is also colored, however, some`\t` does not work.

The output of this one below will have the first two `\t` not working.

`echo "\033[1;31m${var[a]}\t$time\t$end\t$day\t$score\033[m"`

This one below will have all the `\t` working but will also print `-e` in the screen.

`echo -e "\033[1;31m${var[a]}\t$time\t$end\t$day\t$score\033[m"`

Comment: What OS and shell are you using?

Comment: The OS is AIX while shell is ksh.

Comment: Use `printf`. You should probably look at its entry in `ksh --man` or `man ksh` to learn how to use its format strings, too.

Comment: For manuals of built-in commands in [original] `ksh` I prefer `printf --man`, so that I immediately get to the desired information.

Comment: @Janis - then that's what alt123 should look at, but the ANSI escape probably won't work, I think. I'm pretty sure the AIX `ksh` is the 88 variety.

Comment: @mikeserv; The last AIXes I used had indeed ksh88 installed, but that was in the 1990's. - I've been told (but don't know from own experience) that newer versions of AIX would have [also] ksh93 available. - The official ksh93 is at least freely available, so could be installed if need be.

Comment: @mikeserv; Just got that issue confirmed by an AIX using admin: On current AIX'es there's an explicit `ksh93` available, and the also available `ksh` is (for compatibility reasons) a ksh88. - So there should be no issue with availability of ksh's ANSI strings on AIX.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ksh`'s *ANSI strings* feature:

```
echo $'\033[1;31m${var[a]}\t$time\t$end\t$day\t$score\033[m'
```

i.e., your string with ANSI escapes embedded in `$'...'`.

Note: You need a ksh93 (ksh88 does not support that feature).